# Firefox can't save download files on ntfs partition

Tags: 14.04, permissions, firefox, directory, ntfs

Ntfs partition is configured by NTFS configuration tool.

Other browser like chrome have no problem

Showing:

```
"The file could not be saved because you do not have the proper permissions. Choose another save directory."
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Click NTFS partition on unity launcher icon to mount them then try to save.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in firefox - but easy to work around.

Usually, the directory for downloaded files is allways the same, and you make the dialog not ask every time for a directory.

Now, the directory is - for some reason - no longer writable.
Firefox could just tell you, and ask to choose a different download directory.
The bug is that it does not do this last step, and gives you no hint what to do.

But it's easy to go to the preferences dialog, and change the download directory setting, it's on the "General" tab.

You could set it to "Always ask me where to save files", try it, and disable the asking again in the file dialog.

See also [mozilla support: Downloading an update, I get this messa...](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/879768)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the write permission on the directory where you wish to save?
You can also try to run firefox as root, if it works then it is a permission problem.
Use the following:

```
sudo firefox
```

Comment: Running firefox as root is not a good idea for so many reasons - even if it's only for this one test. For example can it create config files owned by root in your home directory, which you can not write later.

Comment: mmm right, probably not the best idea :)

Answer (score 0):

It could mean that your directory doesn't have the required permissions. In my case I could resolve the problem by executing,

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/directory
```